# Getting a name dynamically for attachment with swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

As the title said I would like to pull a input from the form to change the name of the attachment.

When I put this:

```
->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, '$post->name', 'application/pdf'))
```

It doesn't work but if I call out the name like this it works:

```
->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'design.pdf', 'application/pdf'))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `$post->name` without the quotes?

Comment: Don't use the `'` where you have `'$post->name'`- it won't parse the content as a variable. Verify that `$post->name` is what you think it is by `echo`ing it first.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that **a)** `$post->name` isn't what you think it is, and **b)** the single-quotes are messing you up.

First, verify that `$post->name` is a string/filename (such as *design.pdf*):

```
echo $post->name;
exit();
```

Then, once you're sure it's what you're expecting it to be, don't use single-quotes when passing it into a function:

```
->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, $post->name, 'application/pdf'))
```

Single-quote-encased strings are taken literally by PHP, so all you're passing as your filename is `$post->name` instead of the *value* of `$post->name`.  If you want the string to be parsed as containing a variable, use double-quotes instead (`..., "$post->name", ...`) or no quotes at all (since there's no other content to be passed there).

Comment: I tried using the single quotes and that didn't work. I also tried verifying that $post->name is a filename but it gave me an error. I called out the $post->name when I send the email but I dont understand why it wouldn't work for the attachment also. Here is how I do my setTo    
`->setTo(array($post->email => $post->name, 'address@address.com' => 'Eric ')) // Array of people to send to`

Comment: @ehilse ***What was the error?*** That's **very important**. If simply `echo`ing `$post->name` throws an error, what does that tell you?

Comment: "Expected an identifier but found '$post' instead"

Comment: @ehilse There's a problem with `$post`. Figure out why it's throwing an error and you've fixed your problem.

Comment: The thing thats really confusing me is that it pulls its fine when sending the email but wont pull it for the attachment.
`->setSubject('Order Entry') 
->setTo(array($post->email => $post->name, 'ehilse@paifashion.com' => 'Eric Hilse'))
->setFrom(array('cwarhurst@paifashion.com' => 'PAi Order Entry'))
->setBody($html_message, 'text/html') 
->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, $post->name, 'application/pdf'))
->attach($attachment);`

Comment: @ehilse Is *Expected an identifier but found '$post' instead* the **entire** error message?

Comment: It had a line number too but it was no help.

Comment: @ehilse *Are you sure?* Error messages indicate the line at which the error occurred. Looking at where a faulty variable is defined (which could be a few lines above where the error occurred) could solve your problem. Please provide the **entire** error message.

Comment: @ehilse I'm leaving my office to go home soon. I'll try to help you out further when I get home, or perhaps tomorrow. Good luck in the meantime!

Comment: Error
line: 287
message: "Expected an identifier but found '$post' instead"

I only have 251 lines of code. I do have some validation at the bottom but I dont think that would cause it to mess up when the setTo still works.

Comment: Okay... here is the form working [link](http://originalpenguinaccessories.com/captee-form/example2/form2.php)

then here is the form thats not working with $post->name [link](http://originalpenguinaccessories.com/captee-form/example2/form.php)

Comment: @ehilse Unfortunately, I can't debug this for you (as much as I'd like to - I love solving difficult errors). You have to figure out where/why `$post` is being "corrupted". Then, and only then, will your problem be solved.